# Задать patchValue для множества контролов

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4, angular5

Для редактирования профиля пользователя получаю данные в объекте data с сервера и добавляю методом patchValue к форме.

```
this.form.patchValue({ email: data.Email });
this.form.patchValue({ surname: data.LastName });
.....
```

Контролов много, получается 20 почти одинаковых строк. Можно это сделать компактней?

Comment: чтобы это можно было сделать лаконичней - у вас ключи в форме должны совпадать с ключами респонса

Comment: И потом деструктуризацией объекта присвоить значения?

Comment: Нет, потом установить значение сразу на всю форму `this.form.patchValue(data);`